# Is there an API to convert US English (en_US) into UK English (en_GB)?

Tags: localization, internationalization, google-translate

I currently use the Google Translate API (v2) to translate content from US English into various other languages that we support in our software. We then have a process whereby users can submit translation corrections so that we end-up with fairly well-done translations.

We would like to now add support for UK English so that our English-speaking software users in the UK may have a better user experience.

Is there any way to automate the conversion between US English and UK English, or do we just have to manually fix everything?

Comment: The translation/conversion does not have to be comprehensive, as the users will be able to request corrections the same way we have done with other languages, but it will save time with our thousands of internationalized strings to take a first stab through some kind of automated tool.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know of anything automatic. But you could try to identify the most common differences and then search for them.
There is a list here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences

This would at least help with the manual effort.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two tools I have found to do this:

- http://www.us2uk.eu/ (dead website)
- http://www.infoenglish.net/american-to-british-english/

I haven't tried these on large text blocks, however.

There's another tool which is available:

- https://codewordsolver.com/american-british-english-translator (online)
- https://github.com/hyperreality/American-British-English-Translator (source code)

Comment: @davidfraser thanks for the edit. i like the one on GitHub because it's open-sourced, so less likely to just disappear in the future (and could be forked by someone else if abandoned)